# Create a math quiz with LaTex by randomly choosing questions from a bank

Tags: exam

I am looking for a simple solution to the following problem:

I would like to create a math quiz with n questions via LaTex (printable, in pdf) where question 1 is chosen randomly from question bank #1, question 2 is chosen randomly form question bank #2, etc.

Is there a simple way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Andrea

Comment: Did you try the `esami` package?

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/probsoln?lang=en seems to be made exactly to do what you want?

Comment: I did this using a C++ program to write files to be \input by a LaTeX document.  See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm for examples.  I can help you with this, if you are interested.